# Why does "View History" not work for sub module files in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 on a Git repository. Everything works fine, including the Commit/Branch features that were improved in Update 2.

However, when I right-click on any file in a sub module in Solution Explorer, and click View History, I get an empty list saying "The is no history for this item".

Can Visual Studio 2015 handle sub modules?

Answer (score 1):

Some features for git submodules support were implemented in VS 2015 Update 2, but not history support. It just does not work. Some people write something about TFS 2015 in this context - maybe it works only with it. I did not test it like that personally.

You can read more info [under this link](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/3606383-add-submodule-support-in-visual-studio-git-extensi).

We need it in SAAB too because we have quite a big and complex projects and I am sad for it too.